# Recyclerview showing 0 items

Tags: android

I have added items to RecyclerView and set adapter but it is showing zero elements. Means the list is empty. Please check and help me

**ChatAdapter.java**

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
  Context context;
  ArrayList<ChatModel> chatList;

  public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ChatModel> chatList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.chatList = chatList;
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new TextInViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.chat_list_in_text, parent, false));
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    TextInViewHolder hold = (TextInViewHolder) holder;
    hold.tvIncText.setText(chatList.get(position).getText());

  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
  }

  public class TextInViewHolder {

    public TextInViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In getItemCount  your returning 0, return your chatList size

Comment: @BharathKumar please don't answer in comment specially when the answer has been already posted

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh and for you, please don't answer duplicates

Comment: @TimCastelijns i knew someone would come by and say that( but you should have advised both , equality ?) and i follow it many time, just got little existed for with the quicky , BTW the dupe answer had syntax error , fixed that for OP too

Comment: "i knew someone would come by and say that" - yet you still answer it, creating duplicate content

Comment: with due respect, i must say we can have a debate on this , frankly it's been a debate, people understand this when they are open to understand both sides but yet you are only advising me (you like me , i know , i too but as pals only) , i will be more careful , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return size of arraylist in getitemcount.

```
public int getItemCount() {
return chatList.size();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `getItemCunt` you are returning 0

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

instead of returning 0 return list size which is `chatList`

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chatList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace **return 0** by **return chatList.size()**;

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chatList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chatList.size();
}
```

insted of this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in adapter class;

```
@Override
 public int getItemCount() {
    return chatList.size();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

Return size of list if list is not null otherwise 0

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return chatList == null ? 0 : chatList.size();
}
```